# android application not updating field

Tags: java, android

I have the below code, but once I insert the data and press on save it doesn't save the data to the DB. What I am doing wrong?

From IMService.java

```
    @Override
public String updateUserDetails(String username, String statusMessage, String presence)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username.toString(), "UTF-8")
            + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password.toString(), "UTF-8")
            + "&statusmessage=" + URLEncoder.encode(statusMessage, "UTF-8") 
            + "&presence=" + URLEncoder.encode(presence, "UTF-8") 
            + "&action=" + URLEncoder.encode("updateUserData", "UTF-8") + "&";
    Log.i("PARAMS", params);
    return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

}
```

From Main activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");

    statusMsg1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);
    saveStatusBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveStatus);

    saveStatusBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    CharSequence statusMsg;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //test
        statusMsg = statusMsg1.getText();



        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        try {

            imService.updateUserDetails(imService.getUsername(),statusMsg.toString(), "online");



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    });

}
```

Comment: Wen I debug it does give me a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally figured it out, I completely forgot to update the server side code as well, so it was looking for data it wasn't actually querying from the DB. Thanks to all the responses

Answer (score 0):

Whats the point of putting one runnable inside another runnable that is only showing a Toast?
also try assigning the if left side condition to a variable and check it up in debug mode so you can see whats going on in there

Comment: Like I said I am very new to this. but have removed the toast for testing.

Comment: well, post more code then, or explain what yorue trying to do, what database ure trying to save it to, cuz its clearly not SQLite. Also try to print the request youre trying to pass and try it directly in yout web browser

Comment: Hi There. I have tried the code directly in my web browser and it worked perfectly. Will add more code now. It doesn't actually connect straight to a DB but sends parameters to a server via URL. I am getting a nullpointerexception when running the code.